# How to pronounce "$ a:b=c:d$" in English?

Tags: pronunciation

I just realized that I have never used something as simple as **proportions** in *spoken* English so far, but today I have to. So simple question for native speakers: How do you pronounce for example
$$ a:b=c:d$$
where the colon denotes a proportion rather than a division? (For example, in German we'd say "$a$ zu $b$ wie $c$ zu $d$" for proportions  as opposed to "$a$ durch $b$ gleich $c$ durch $d$" for divisions).

Comment: I've just enriched my German by approximately $800\%$.

Comment: @barakmanos 800%? With me writing just 4 different German words? ;) You must have known more than half a German word before, at least things like *Kindergarten* or *Nullstellensatz*

Comment: Well... $800\%$ assuming "Achtung" and "Baby" are both in German.

Comment: @barakmanos are you sure you didn't enrich it by '1 *zu* 800'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"$a$ is to $b$ as $c$ is to $d$."

Or,

"The ratio of $a$ to $b$ is equal to the ratio of $c$ to $d$."

On a rather pedantic note, this isn't an issue of "pronunciation" *per se*, but one of "verbalization."  How do we speak or *verbalize* a mathematical construct (in this case, an equation between proportions).

Answer (score 4):

In English, we pronounce $a:b :: c:d$ as "*a is to b **as** b is to c*", where the *colon* in particular is pronounced "*is to*".
 The $::$ sign that I have used in place of the equality sign is the *proportionality* sign.  
 So if you wish to say $a:b = c:d$, then you will say "*a is to b **is equal to** b is to c*".

Comment: Ah, so mathematical proportions are indeed pronounced (or verbalized, as I just learned) just like those pseudo-relations from intelligence tests "dog is to bark as cat is to ...?"

Comment: "a is to b **is equals to** b is to c" is wrong. At the very least it should be "a is to b **is equal to** b is to c", but even then I doubt many people would say it that way.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed they are.  We also use the same phrasing in geometry; e.g., for similar triangles, we might say "side $A$ is to side $A'$ as side $B$ is to side $B'$."  Those "pseudo-relations" are called "analogies" in the parlance of the standardized tests in which they have traditionally appeared.

Comment: @joriki It was just a typo. Corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: My first thought was to verbalize the equality sign the same as I would the double colon; that is, the intent is the same. If I _had_ to use some form of the word "equal", I would probably say "the ratio of $a$ to $b$ equals the ratio of $c$ to $d$". But I'd rather not do that.

Comment: @DavidK How would you verbalise the equality sign? Without using the standard "is equal to" ?

Comment: "The same as I would the double colon," that is, "$a$ is to $b$ as $b$ is to $c$". (In short, I agree with heropup's answer.) Why should we always have to use the same word for the same symbol every single time? Or different words for different symbols every single time?